# Angular Typeahead not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to use the Angular directive for Typeahead to load and search in my database. The problem is that the suggestions only show "undefined" when I'm searching.

My HTML looks like this:

```
          <h4>Asynchronous results</h4>
            <pre>Model: {{asyncSelected | json}}</pre>
            <input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="person for object in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control">
            <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
            <div ng-show="noResults">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {

  var data = {
    searchString: val
  };

  return $http.post('/api/search', data).then(function(response){

    console.log(transformSearchResults(response));

    /*Returns an array of objects like this:

    [
      {
      name: "Peter Pan",
      address: "Neverland 944"
      }
    ]

    */

    return transformSearchResults(response);
  });
};
```

I'm ultimately trying to filter by both name and address, but I guess I need to get the basics working first.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try  to assign the list

//you code here

$scope.viewvalue = '?'; 
$scope.list = $scope.getLocation( $scope.viewvalue );

// html 
// typeahead="person for object in list"